# What CI tool satisfies the following requirements?

Tags: continuous-integration

**Requirements**

- Local deployment using RPM
- GitHub Enterprise integration
- Compilation of Golang

---

**Potential**

- TravisCI
- Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

All the above said requirements are not applicable to CI tools instead it is applicable for the environment you use. Both TravisCI and Jenkins will able to integrate with github integration. The other things can be done through shell commands under pre/post build actions  in the CI tools.

Answer (score 0):

Both TravisCI and Jenkins, *and a few others* are:

- Available for local deployment on a number of platforms and in a number of package formats.
- Can integrate with various VCSs including git, hg, svn, etc., so github should be no problem.
- Can compile and build anything that you can compile and build from the command line given a tool chain that you can use from the command line.